# Shifting time of a signal

Tags: matlab

Considering a signal `x = t.*(2*t + 4)`

In case I want to time shift the signal -let's say 2 time-values to the right- is it possible to do something like

```
x = x(t-2)
```

In order to shift all the values ? 
I stumbled across `circshift` but I didn't find any use for my case

**EDIT:** I'm searching for a solution where it will work for every signal, as an example if I reflect x (or do anything on it) and store it on Y, how should I time shift Y?

Comment: Are you working symbolically? Would you like your signal to wrap around? If not, what do you want to happen to the 2 edge points on both sides? If you want a new formula, just replace `t` with `(t-2)` right in the equation...

Comment: That is not possible because I first need to reflect the signal and then time shift it.

Comment: This information needs to be a part of the question! Otherwise, you might answers about what you asked, but it later turns out that there are new constraints and the answers are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the signal as a function, so that you can then shift it as you wish.

For instance,

```
x = @(t) t.*(2*t + 4); % A function x(t)
y = @(t) x(-t); % A reflected version of the function
z = @(t,a) x(t-a); % A delayed version of the function 

t = -5:0.01:5; % Sampling instants

X = x(t); % A vector of samples of the original signal
Y = x(t-2); % A vector of samples of the delayed signal
```

Note that if you want to define operators that can reflect and shift any function, you can e.g. write

```
Rop = @(s,t) s(-t);
Sop = @(s,a,t) s(t-a);
```

And you can use them on the `x` signal as

```
Rop(x,[-2 -1 0 1 2]) % Calculates x([2 1 0 -1 -2])
Sop(x,5,[1 2 3 4 5]) % Calculates x([-4 -3 -2 -1 0])
```

If you want to combine shifting and reflection, you can do like this:

```
Rop(@(t) Sop(x,2,t),[1 2 3 4 5]) % First shifts x by 2, then reflects
Sop(@(t) Rop(x,t),2,[1 2 3 4 5]) % First reflects x, and then shifts by 2
```

If you run the above code you will see that reflection and shift are not commutative because the resulting vectors are different.

Comment: In case I modify the signal x first, by lets say a reflection of itself, how should I time shift the reflection ?

Comment: @Theo.Fanis E.g. `x(-t+3)` is the signal reflected and shifted.

Comment: So reflecting and then time shifting is the same process as shifting and then reflecting ?

Comment: On a theoretical level, is there a way of taking `y = x(-t)` and then time shifting `y` separately?

Comment: @Theo.Fanis You lack a bit of mathematical background. The shift and the reflections operator are not commutative, because there is a change of sign: if I denote by R the reflection operator and by Sa the shift operator by a, then RSa is different from SaR, in fact RSa maps   x(t) to x(-t-a) whereas SaR maps x(t) to x(-(t-a))=x(-t+a) (note the change in sign of a). For your second question, indeed yes: define another function ;-)

Comment: ok thank you, how should I define the other function for y though?

Comment: @Theo.Fanis Exactly as any other matlab function. If you want to use [anonymous functions](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) (please, read the Matlab help), you can simply write `y = @(t) x(-t);`

Comment: You've been very helpful! Edit the answer and put there the conclusion from the comments so I can give you the thumbs up.

Comment: @Theo.Fanis Done, I've added some other stuff too.